# Unknown Login on C# sqlconnector

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database, xampp

We're having trouble getting our program to open a connection to our sql database

We're hosting the sql database installed with xampp on another computer and developing and testing this code on another. The computer holding the code has been tested and is able to connect to the host computer and can access the database as well as

We already have our code below but we're getting an inner exception "unknown username or bad password". We understand that Visual Studio has already connected to the sql database because under Server Explorer we can see database rows that were manually inputted before. Our troubleshooting was as follows:

> We were thinking before that it might have been with the connection string but this seemed ok as it was copied from the connection string generated by visual studio. 
>   We also checked with the sql database and no users or groups were overwriting the credentials that we were using. 
>   We already turned off our firewalls
>   upon testing on the remote computer,our credentials (not root, custom made ones) can write manually on the database

Is there anything we missed?

Thank you

```
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=192.168.0.128;Database=transaction_table;user id=new;database=transaction_table");
        try
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message + "\n\n" + ex.Message );
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find Updated Code
when u host outside domain password is must

```
con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=192.168.0.128;Database=transaction_table;user id=new;password:abc123");
    try
    {
        con.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message + "\n\n" + ex.Message );
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

We opted to use MySQL.Data.dll instead. Problem was with the connector we used earlier